# Make URLs of flair image representing your votes in the final phase HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-planned, election, flair, ssl

I have cast my 3 votes in the [final phase of the Ask Ubuntu elections 2016](https://askubuntu.com/election/5?tab=election) and now my Firefox browser warns me because of mixed HTTP/HTTPS content.

Examining this further, the only HTTP content are the user flair images that appear in the right sidebar to show me for whom I voted, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/users/flair/367990.png

You should edit the elections page to load the flair images via HTTPS. They're already provided through both protocols, so it should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The flair image URLs are https on all sites as of build (build rev `2017.1.6.24567`). You can verify it on the flair tab in [your preferences](/users/preferences).</strike>

The URLs to the profile are still http, as https is still WIP.

#### UPDATE

We've reverted the code, since we still don't have the https infrastructure in place to support that on child metas, which also have flair. This will be available as soon as we figure out child meta domain certificates.